# Android: blank image when using TouchImageView with Android-Query

Tags: android, android-query, touchimageview

I'm loading several images inside a `Fragment` using Android-Query library. When I press on an image, a new `Activity` starts, showing that image in fullscreen mode -> in my case all I see is a blank image...

```
public class FullScreenImage extends Activity {

    String[] imageUrls = Data.Cars;
    private AQuery aq;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_pager_image);

        aq = new AQuery(this);       

        Intent i = getIntent();

        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        if(i.getExtras().containsKey("id")){
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    } else {
        this.finish();
    }

        final TouchImageView FullImage = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_no1);
     // FullImage.setZoom(1); <- tried this but it's not working
        aq.id(R.id.image_no1).progress(R.id.loading).image(imageUrls[position], false, false);    

    }
}
```

Comment: debug the value of the variable "position".

Comment: never did that before, and I'm getting an error when using the Debug tool: `Warning: debug info can be unavailable...`

Comment: You can toast the value or can print in log.

Comment: Not getting anywhere... guess I'll have to find another library ( PhotoView maybe).